# python-selenium and ChromeDriver: Can't open tab to control it

Tags: python, selenium

I'm unable to open a new tab - or even click on a link and open it on a new tab - with Python 2.7.1, Selenium 2.53.0, ChromeDriver 2.22 and Google Chrome 51.0 on Mac OS X.

```
 import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
 import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
 from time import sleep

 driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')

 driver.get('https://twitter.com')
 driver.find_element_by_id('signin-email').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

It opens the URL, but it doesn't open a new tab.

I've also tested opening a new tab with ActionChains, but no success.

The only method to open new tab that works is with JavaScript through `execute_script()`, but I'm not able to control the new tab in that case. `switch_to.window()` doesn't work.

Comment: after you download chromedriver in Mac, chromedriver-2.22 is its name?  try `driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver-2.22/chromedriver')` ?

Comment: Yes, I renamed it with -2.22 as I tested multiple versions (1.9 and 2.9) to see if tabs could open. No success.

Comment: try this ... `.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + Keys.RETURN);`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Yes! COMMAND + RETURN does work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_id('signin-email').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + Keys.RETURN);
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to click on the link while holding the `ctrl` key, this will open the link in new tab

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
driver.find_element_by_id('signin-email').click()
actions.key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```